# sql insert based on result from select

Tags: sql, insert

I have a one table with a primary key that goes up by one each time (serial, just not constrained as serial), and I have to insert another value into it. Example table:

```
table1
tbl1-num
1
```

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (tbl1-num) 
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(tbl1-num)) + 1)
```

Would that work?

So in the end I want to have the table be something like

table1

```
tbl1-num
1
2
```

Comment: Just make it auto increment!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have two option:

1) Using a select a value for  each column like:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (col1) VALUES ((SELECT isnull(MAX(col1),0) from  table_1) + 1)
```

And 
2) Using a select a query to insert a row like:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (col1)
select isnull(MAX(col1),0)+1 from table_1
```